# JQuery UI - Limit draggable to elements tagged with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to confine a draggable TD to only elements which have a specific class.

The basic idea is an element tagged with draggable can only be dragged to a dropable element.

```
<table>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>Header 1</td> <!-- can't drag here -->
           <td>Header 1</td> <!-- can't drag here -->
           <td>Header 1</td> <!-- can't drag here -->
           <td class="draggable">draggable TD</td> <-- draggable td -->
           <td class="droppable">droppable area</td> <-- draggable area -->
           <td class="droppable">droppable area</td> <-- draggable area -->
           <td class="droppable">droppable area</td> <-- draggable area -->
           <td class="droppable">droppable area</td> <-- draggable area -->
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I've read the Jquery UI documentation however it appears the only way to really restrict a draggable is to either the parent container or a wrapped DIV but in a table this isn't really possible.

```
  <table>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>Header 1</td> <!-- can't drag here -->
               <td>Header 1</td> <!-- can't drag here -->
               <td>Header 1</td> <!-- can't drag here -->
               <div class="container"> <-- INVALID HTML -->
                   <td class="draggable">draggable TD</td> <-- draggable td -->
                   <td class="droppable">droppable area</td> <-- draggable area -->
                   <td class="droppable">droppable area</td> <-- draggable area -->
                   <td class="droppable">droppable area</td> <-- draggable area -->
                   <td class="droppable">droppable area</td> <-- draggable area -->
                </div>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
```

Update: JSFiddle showing the issue http://jsfiddle.net/d7wsz/67

Comment: Hello, Yes see I have mocked up an example see http://jsfiddle.net/d7wsz/67/ . 

If you specify the containment option as your droppable class when your drag the element it gets stuck on the first .droppable element the selector could find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution using a regular table without using non valid HTML. In the end I went for a DIV based table which met requirements and allowed me to wrap each group of 'TDs' in a containment DIV.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which table columns will act as droppable (using the class)

```
$( "td.droppable" ).droppable();
```

Comment: Hmm I don't think you digested my question Daniel. 

My goal is find a way to contain a draggable elements movement to other elements which have been tagged with our containment class.

Comment: You're right. In that case I would use multiple <tbody>. That makes for valid HTML and allows you to contain rows inside an element.

Comment: Unfortunately multiple <tbody> tags won't cut the mustard as I'm working with a single row of content (each tbody must contain atleast one TR http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_tbody.asp)